# Core Data to-many relationship get data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my code i want to create tableView with List sections. I use scheme like this one:

[image]

I use NSFetchResultController which i define in this way:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataController.masterManagedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"addedAt" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemIsChecked = 1"];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:coreDataController.masterManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"toList.listName"
                                               cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Now in cellForRowAtIndexPath: i want to get data form my fetchResultController, so i do this in way:

```
Item *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and then if i want to access one of the item's field (for example itemText), it crash:

```
NSLog(@"item itemtext = %@", item.itemText);
```

with error:

```
-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 itemText]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1215fd90
```

What i do wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set

```
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

and therefore the fetched results controller returns `NSDictionary` objects, not `Item` objects. So your element

```
Item *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

is a `NSDictionary`, not an `Item`. Since dictionaries do not have a `itemText` method, `item.itemText` crashes. You could retrieve the value from the dictionary with

```
NSDictionary *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"item itemtext = %@", [item objectForKey:@"itemText"]);
```

But if you don't have a specific reason to set the result type to `NSDictionaryResultType`, you should just delete that line. Change tracking of the fetched results controller (i.e. automatic table view updates) do not work with `resultType == NSDictionaryResultType`.

Note also that if you have set a `sectionNameKeyPath`, then you must add a sort descriptor with the same key path "toList.listName" and use it as first sort descriptor for the fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

`unrecognized selector sent to instance` generally occurs due to bad memory management. Check if you are trying to point an object which was released earlier. Also check for IBOutlet connection in xib for lable `itemText`.